# Redirection to subdirectory with name in URL

Tags: .htaccess

Domain : domain.com
Subdirectory: nz

Scenarios:

- domain.com -> domain.com/nz/
- domain.com/anything/ -> domain.com/nz/anything/
- domain.com/404page -> domain.com/nz/404page

EDIT

- Also in scenario - domain.com/nz -> domain.com/nz

How to achieve this with .htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RedirectMatch ^/(?!nz/)(.*)$ /nz/$1
```

or:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!nz/)(.*)$ /nz/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: Good one liner solution - top one. The only problem is when I try to open domain.com/nz it opens domain.com/nz/nz - How do I stop that?

Comment: @KaranKhanna Try changing the regex pattern to `(?!nz/?)`

Comment: @KaranKhanna If `nz` is a directory, you're not going to be able to go there without apache redirecting to include a trailing slash. This is because there's a way to bypass directory index if there is no trailing slash (thus listing the contents of any directory).

Comment: What would be the way to exclude a file from this rule? For example domain.com/something.php should always be domain.com/something.php ?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to the `.htaccess` file in your web document root folder (often `public_html` or `htdocs`):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(?!nz) nz%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R,DPI]
```

Once you are satisfied that the redirect works, you can change the `R` to `R=301` to make it permanent.

This assumes that mod_rewrite is **both** installed **and** activated for `.htaccess` files. 
If you are not sure, to check if mod_rewrite is even installed, look at the list of installed modules in the output of `phpinfo();`
By default, mod_rewrite is not enabled for `.htaccess` files. If you are managing your own server, open `httpd.conf`
and make sure that the webroot directory block contains one of these lines: `AllowOverride FileInfo` or `AllowOverride All`